# Directions in mapView

Tags: android

In my mapView I have an overlay in my current location but I need to insert a direction to an editText and that my map add an overlay there.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you clarify "I need to insert a direction to an editText and that my map add an overlay there"

Comment: You should insert your direction (e.g. 234 Elm Street) and the map add an overlay there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You will need to:

1. Get the text from the input box
2. Lookup the address using [Google Goelocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/)
3. Parse the results
4. Add a marker at the lat/lng of the destination

If you need help getting started, [read this tutorial](http://blog.synyx.de/2010/06/routing-driving-directions-on-android-part-1-get-the-route/)